# Selecting rows after a specific value occurrs in r

Tags: r, select, filter, row

I just want to select all the rows (including the row itself) of my data frame between the value "openwebsite" and "closewebsite" (see variable "activity"). Do I need to use the select- or filter-function?

Thank you a lot!

**Dataframe:**

| Person | activity | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | write | 9 |
| 1 | openwebsite | 8 |
| 1 | paint | 9 |
| 1 | write | 2 |
| 1 | write | 4 |
| 1 | closewebsite | 9 |
| 1 | write | 4 |

**Output**

| Person | activity | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | openwebsite | 8 |
| 1 | paint | 9 |
| 1 | write | 2 |
| 1 | write | 4 |
| 1 | closewebsite | 9 |

Answer (score 1):

You may try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter(1 == cumsum((activity == "openwebsite") - 
                       lag(activity == "closewebsite", default = 0)))

  Person     activity duration
1      1  openwebsite        8
2      1        paint        9
3      1        write        2
4      1        write        4
5      1 closewebsite        9
```

or

```
df %>%
  filter(1 <= cumsum(activity == "openwebsite"),
         lag(cumsum(activity == "closewebsite")) < 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
start_row <- (1:nrow(df))[df$activity == "openwebsite"]
end_row <- (1:nrow(df))[df$activity == "closewebsite"]
df[start_row:end_row,]

  Person     activity duration
2      1  openwebsite        8
3      1        paint        9
4      1        write        2
5      1        write        4
6      1 closewebsite        9
```

You can also get the start and end row number with `grep`, e.g.

```
grep("openwebsite", df$activity)
```